# Validating an input string against some enum fields

Tags: java, enum

I have this enum below:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    h1, h2, h3, h4;

    public static String forCode(int code) {
    return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestEnum.h1.name());
        String ss = "h3";

        try {
           TestEnum.valueOf(ss); // but this validates with all the enum values
           System.out.println("valid");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           System.out.println("invalid");
        }           
    }
}
```

I need to check if the enum value represented by my string `ss` is one of my enum values `h1`, `h2` or `h4`. So if `h3` is being passed as a string, I would like to return false or throw `IllegalArgumentException`. I won't need to validate `ss` with `h3` in the enum.

I came up with the below code to do this with the enum, but I believe there is a more elegant solution.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    h1, h2, h3, h4;

    public static boolean checkExcept(String el, TestEnum... except){
        boolean results = false;
        try{
            results = !Arrays.asList(except).contains(TestEnum.valueOf(el));
        }catch (Exception e){}
        return results;
    }

    public static String forCode(int code) {
        return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ss = "h3";

        if(TestEnum.checkExcept(ss,TestEnum.h1, TestEnum.h2, TestEnum.h3)){
           System.out.println("valid");
        }else{
           System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would pass a `TestEnum` instead of a `String` to your method, forcing the exception handling to be outside the method. I don't see why you are using Strings at all actually (although I suspect that this is only a small part of your code, and that you have your reasons for needing this).

I would do some refactoring and use [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), which could make your code something like this: (untested code, but I believe it should work)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String enumName = "h3";
    EnumSet<TestEnum> except = EnumSet.of(TestEnum.h1, TestEnum.h2, TestEnum.h3);

    boolean valid;
    try {
       valid = !except.contains(TestEnum.valueOf(enumName));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { valid = false; }
    System.out.println(valid ? "valid" : "invalid");
}
```

Note that I have gotten rid of your entire method here as I think that when you use EnumSet like this, you don't need the method. But of course you can put the relevant parts of the above code into a method.

Comment: What about if the String enumName is `h10`? It should return false as well? Correct? But it is throwing exception with your current code.

Comment: @user2809564 As if that's a big problem to solve.... ;) See edit.

Comment: @ringbearer If you pass `enumName = "h4"` in this case it is a valid enum and will not throw, but `contains` will return `false`.

Comment: Right, i assumed before noting that OP wanted a filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `isValid` or `checkValid` method inside the enum and override it in `h3` if it's not changing runtime.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    h1, 
    h2, 
    h3 {
        @Override
        public boolean isValid() {
            return false;
        }
    },
    h4;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It returns `true` for `h1`, `h2` and `h4`, `false` for `h3`.

You could eliminate the `results` variable from checkExcept:

```
public static boolean checkExcept(String el, TestEnum... except) {
    try {
        return !Arrays.asList(except).contains(TestEnum.valueOf(el));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please note that [catching Exception is almost always a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2416316/843804). I'd catch a more specific exception here (`IllegalArgumentException`).

Comment: Overriding the isValid method is not a flexible solution for different validation requirements. I agree with catching IllegalArgumentException though.

Answer (score 2):

Catching exception or its sub type is bad idea.
This should do it more proper way as mentioned code below.

```
public static boolean contains(String test) {

    for (EnumType type : EnumType.values()) {
        if (type.name().equals(test)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is generally a good option, but in this case it doesn't solve the same problem. The question asks for *I need to check if the enum value represented by my string `ss` is one of my enum values h1, h2 or h4. So if h3 is being passed as a string, I would like to return false or throw IllegalArgumentException.*